# watchOS 3.0 detect crown rotation in SpriteKit

Tags: sprite-kit, watchkit, swift3, xcode8, watchos-3

So as of watchOS 3.0 you are now able to get the rotation of the digital crown. I managed to use the [crownDidRotate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkcrowndelegate/1650886-crowndidrotate) function in an InterfaceController.
But I can't get the rotation of the crown from inside a SKScene Class. 
Can anybody help me with this I'm pretty lost right now?
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get those `crownDidRotate` calls in your interface controller, you had to adopt the [`WKCrownDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkcrowndelegate) protocol in your interface controller, and set your interface controller as the [`delegate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkcrownsequencer/1650887-delegate) of its `crownSequencer`.

To get `crownDidRotate` calls in some other class, adopt the [`WKCrownDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkcrowndelegate) protocol in that class, and set an instance of that class as the [`delegate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkcrownsequencer/1650887-delegate) of your interface controller's `crownSequencer`.

Presumably you already have some code like this to set up your SpriteKit scene:

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

    @IBOutlet var spriteGizmo: WKInterfaceSKScene!

    override func awake(withContext context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)

        let scene = MyScene(fileNamed: "MyScene")
        spriteGizmo.presentScene(MyScene(fileNamed: "MyScene"))
    }
}
```

If you've declared [`WKCrownDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkcrowndelegate) conformance in your `MyScene` class, just add a line to set it as the delegate of the interface controller's crown sequencer:

```
let scene = MyScene(fileNamed: "MyScene")
spriteGizmo.presentScene(MyScene(fileNamed: "MyScene"))
crownSequencer.delegate = scene
```

(Alternatively, you may set your `WKInterfaceSKScene`'s scene in the Storyboard. In that case, you can still reference the `WKInterfaceSKScene` from your interface controller with an `IBOutlet`. Then in `awake(withContext:)`, you can access the scene through that outlet and set it as the crown delegate.)

Answer (score 0):

In watchOS 3 just any object object can get digital crown events by setting them as a delegate:

```
let crownSequencer = WKExtension.shared().rootInterfaceController!.crownSequencer
crownSequencer.delegate = self
crownSequencer.focus()
```

Then read back the value by implementing:

```
func crownDidRotate(_ crownSequencer: WKCrownSequencer?, rotationalDelta: Double)
```

It is important to call the `focus()`, especially for controllers whose UI fits the screen and do not need actual scrolling.